# how to store and which object should be use to store value for the later usage

Tags: asp.net

I have a three texbox and Next and Prevoius BUTTON .

When i click on next, next value with respect to AUTOGENERATED ID should be fetch and when i click on previous ,prevoius value should be fetch.

let suppose, i am displaying current record as 2 ,when i click on next 3 should be display,
but when i click on previous 1 should be display.

But my problem is that each time whenever i click on **NEXT** or **PREVOIUS** button i have to get data from the database .I dont want to do this i want to store previous and next record in some object.how will i do so.I dont want to use viewstate or cache or session or application object .Is there any diffenrent logic .please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you dont load the page again, use an `asp:HiddenField` to store that value.

Or... use cookies

Then you check if the hidden field or specific cookie has any value assigned

1. Create a cookie that stores the data you got from database.
2. Check if cookie is not null, if true get it's value else go to
   database and create the cookie with the value

**how to manipulate cookies:**

```
    HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies
.Add(new HttpCookie("myCookie", "1"){ Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(5) });

   var myCookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["myCookie"];
   if (myCookie != null)
       Response.Write(myCookie.Value);
```

Comment: So, use `Cookies` is client side state.